# Merge two lists based on common parts of a string

Tags: python, list, merge

Suppose I have the following two lists:

```
list1=["Equipment ONLY - Bees Technologies","Bees Technologies","Chris Metal SA - Central Office","NSA Aerospace tech"]

list2=["Bees Tech, Inc.","Chris Metal, SA","NSA Arerospace"]
```

how can I merge the two lists to get the following:

```
final_list=["Equipment ONLY - Bees Technologies","Bees Technologies", "Bees Tech, Inc.", "Chris Metal SA - Central Office", "Chris Metal, SA","NSA Aerospace tech", "NSA Arerospace"]
```

Comment: ``final_list = list1 + list2`` ?

Comment: If each item in list 1 corresponds to one item in list 2, you might use Levensthein Distance or similar to determine which item it corresponds to and sort accordingly.

Comment: var  list3 = list1.Union(list2).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

I think sorting the list is what you're looking for:

```
list1=["Equipment ONLY - Bees Technologies","Bees Technologies","Chris Metal SA - Central Office","NSA Aerospace tech"]
list2=["Bees Tech, Inc.","Chris Metal, SA","NSA Arerospace"]

list1.extend(list2)
list1.sort()

print(list1) # Result : ['Bees Tech, Inc.', 'Bees Technologies', 'Chris Metal SA - Central Office', 'Chris Metal, SA', 'Equipment ONLY - Bees Technologies', 'NSA Aerospace tech', 'NSA Arerospace']
```

***EDIT***

If you're looking only for merge them it can be done by :

```
list1.extend(list2)
```

or by :

```
list1 = list1 + list2
```

Comment: Neither of those matches OP's expected output.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
final_list = sorted(list1 + list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear what you are looking for. If you want to sort "matching" items from `list1` and `list2` together, you could try to find the best match using [`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html). Assuming the (unique) elements in `list2` are the prototypes you want to sort the elements from `list1` to:

```
list1=["Equipment ONLY - Bees Technologies","Bees Technologies","Chris Metal SA - Central Office","NSA Aerospace tech"]
list2=["Bees Tech, Inc.","Chris Metal, SA","NSA Arerospace"]

import difflib
groups = {a: [] for a in list2}
for b in list1:
    a = max(list2, key=lambda a: difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=a, b=b).ratio())
    groups[a].append(b)
# {'Bees Tech, Inc.': ['Equipment ONLY - Bees Technologies', 'Bees Technologies'],
#  'Chris Metal, SA': ['Chris Metal SA - Central Office'],
#  'NSA Arerospace': ['NSA Aerospace tech']}

res = [x for a in groups for x in (*groups[a], a)]
# ['Equipment ONLY - Bees Technologies', 'Bees Technologies', 'Bees Tech, Inc.', 'Chris Metal SA - Central Office', 'Chris Metal, SA', 'NSA Aerospace tech', 'NSA Arerospace']
```